# What's the fastest way to find the number of elements that satisfy a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know the fastest way to find the number of elements in a list that satisfy a condition, not the elements themselves, just their count.

Let me explain: I already know how to find the elements that meet a condition as fast as possible, that is, using the `filter()` method. But `filter` returns a generated object that does not have `__len__()` method. To get the length of the `filter` object, we have to either use a loop to count its elements manually, which takes a lot of time, or we can convert the object to a list which will take a huge amount of RAM if the object contains too many elements.

Let me illustrate this better: I have written a brute force function that approximates pi by summing the area of disks using pixels. (I have already written a function that uses Lebniz's method and another that uses Liu Hui's.)

The basic idea is, if a pixel's x^2+y^2<=r^2 then it's inside a circle.

Here is the code:

```
from itertools import product

def pi(r):
    quardrant = product(range(r+1), repeat=2)
    quarterdisk = filter(lambda p: p[0]**2 + p[1]**2 <= r**2, quardrant)
    return (4*len(list(quarterdisk)) - 4*r + 4) / r**2
```

If I input 10000, the first two lines run pretty fast, but the third line takes forever and uses up to 14 gibibytes of RAM out of 16 GiB RAM!

Now if I get the length using a loop, it takes significantly less RAM however it also takes even longer time to compute!

So what is the best method to find the number of elements that meet a requirement in an extremely long list?

Comment: What about calling `sum` on a map that holds `True`/`False` ?

Comment: The first two lines only seem fast because they are only creating generator objects, no computation takes place until the third line when you convert to a list

Comment: Do you really need the question answered exactly as is? Even supposing you need to calculate pi for some reason, and that you can't use any of the much faster formulas, it would still be much faster to compute (directly) the number of points on each line satisfying the condition (by calculating the maximum X value corresponding to a point inside the circle at that Y) rather than check and count them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, pre-compute values you use more than once, for example, `r**2`. With r=1000, this made it about 30% faster for me (~1.1s → ~.85s total run time).

```
r_sq = r**2
```

---

Next, to save memory, don't make a list of a filter when all you need to know is its length. Instead, sum over a map, or better yet, a generator expression:

```
q = sum(x**2 + y**2 <= r_sq for x, y in quardrant)
return (4*q - 4*r + 4) / r_sq
```

This saves a bit of time by not constructing a list, but as a bonus, using unpacking instead of indexing also saves a surprising amount of time -- about 7% for me (~.74s → ~.69s total run time).

---

Next, coming back to the first point, if you think about it, you're getting `x` and `y` from a `product`, which means you're calculating the square of each number 0..`r`, 2*`r` times. It'd be faster to calculate the squares ahead of time.

```
quardrant_sq = product((x**2 for x in range(r+1)), repeat=2)
q = sum(a+b <= r_sq for a, b in quardrant_sq)
```

This gives a **massive** improvement, about 250% faster! (~.66s → ~.19s total run time).

---

Lastly, since you're dealing with only numbers, you could look into using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html#what-is-numpy) to further optimize your code.